# PHP redirect to same page after login

Tags: php

I have a login box on every page and when the user login I try to redirect the user to the same page and it works fine untill I have a variable in the url like
http://www.mypage.com/post?id=1

Then I get an error Notice: Undefined index: id in...

I use session to keep track of urls, like

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$url = $_SESSION['url'];
header("Location:".$url."");
```

I use $_GET['id'] to fetch data from the database and I know thats where the problem is, but I dont know how to solve it.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it very much.

Update
The login works fine but I cant fetch the data from the database when the user login because the id variable is empty.

I try to explain a little bit better, sorry for my poor english btw.
When a user click on this link http://www.mypage.com/post?id=1 and then
tries to login it works. But what happens is that I cant fetch the data
from the database using $_GET['id'] beacuse it's empty.

I get an error Notice: Undefined index: id in...

Comment: $_GET['whatsoever'] does not check if sth is set or not, it tries to pull it and if does not work, you will get an empty variable. So use isset() to check if $_GET['whatsoever'] is set

Comment: $_GET['id'] is always empty. If I echo the session it look like this http://www.mypage.com/post.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in...
Means, that your script wants to use $_GET['id'] but it is not found. look at the other answers for further informations :)

Comment: You are confusing your question. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can append id to the URL. For example

```
$id = $_GET['post_id'];
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$url = $_SESSION['url'];
header("Location:".$url."?post_id=".$id);
```

**UPDATE**
You can also check if post_id is set or not to confirm if you want to concatenate variable to URL or not.

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$url = $_SESSION['url'];
if(isset($_GET['post_id']){
   $url='?post_id='.$_GET['post_id'];
}
header("Location:".$url.");
```

Comment: So I have to use a different $url on every page I have? What if I have another page like http://www.mypage.com/topic?id=1

Comment: Yes, if there are more than one variables in URL like http://abc.or?id=1&cat_id=3. You can loop through $_GET variable and append in the URL you are getting in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: When an user click on this link http://www.mypage.com/post?id=1 and then tries to login the id=1 is gone and I get an error.

Comment: One second, what do you get in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Answer (score -1):

Use This Header Code inside valid login condition block for redirect in same page.

```
header("Location:".$url."");die;
```

Comment: In what way does the above code answer his question? And what does `$location` contain?

Comment: It should be added once logged in condition is checked.